# How to interpret the Descriptor field?

Tags: utxo, utxo-set, p2wpkh, output-script-descriptors

These are my UTXO in Tesnet environment:

```
  {
    "txid": "93ae7787fe8203e9f13534205ca0310baf8bf5e2b55b2faa1f8b09134f475208",
    "vout": 1,
    "address": "2N4VywDy3DnkCmCM8yvfMSFHiEt2ePxzLXu",
    "label": "",
    "redeemScript": "0014e700e862aa81cba9b43ede7bf446bebe91a5b147",
    "scriptPubKey": "a9147b73e47479d05d755dbaee6bdedf430df05ca34587",
    "amount": 0.01593294,
    "confirmations": 116,
    "spendable": true,
    "solvable": true,
    "desc": "sh(wpkh([7de694b7/0'/0'/8']030268ac0849999b04d572ddcf4202dbc8399e680df2afe4a577c1ed8e048d06f5))#zy9vsk5a",
    "safe": true
  },
  {
    "txid": "aaec2330d2d8a19e036cf2cde6575cfae299e303a4140451f2f88142491c9439",
    "vout": 0,
    "address": "2N7MaihNErbNH8XTkuZWtJYPzMQAWMPVKHd",
    "label": "",
    "redeemScript": "0014778daf651b21684b572644b47d551fce0ff71c74",
    "scriptPubKey": "a9149ac58ff47e27214b158b38da04bc8cbf72def14387",
    "amount": 0.01643138,
    "confirmations": 343,
    "spendable": true,
    "solvable": true,
    "desc": "sh(wpkh([7de694b7/0'/0'/7']032c27921f2d15e7eca768c0e8a8b1aeb863328c74d6c194d41dde2888d4b0e75b))#6z7uwusp",
    "safe": true
  },
  {
    "txid": "dbf77cfb45314d925ae99d40267419ba23d03200ae2ffdd5a54c06661c934242",
    "vout": 1,
    "address": "2NGS7agzTfk9LEKXkm89QvgbCC7rHWHBD4K",
    "label": "",
    "redeemScript": "00141212e2e581101ca9d211cef24ffe04196887aa8f",
    "scriptPubKey": "a914fe5a1ed871c6bd7fa9bb2dffbdcc77da4cd2b40e87",
    "amount": 0.00010000,
    "confirmations": 52732,
    "spendable": true,
    "solvable": true,
    "desc": "sh(wpkh([7de694b7/0'/0'/3']02902a17c3010900ddee53be420c7660f016c2a36cf169b45afc6747ea1a81e3a2))#ckzssh4n",
    "safe": true
  },
```

From the documentation found the descriptor field `sh (wpkh)`describes a P2SH-P2WPKH output with the specified public key. Within wpkh and wsh, only compressed public keys are allowed. 
How can I check the link between this key and the address? Why the fingerprint `7de694b7` is the same for all keys?
I tried to perform these steps without getting a result:

1. SHA256 of the key
2. RIPEMD160 of the previous result
3. I added the prefix (trying both 0xc4 and 0x6F)
4. base58 including checksum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key descriptors describe a p2sh-p2wpkh address. The descriptor can be decoded as:

```
sh # p2sh script
(
wpkh # p2pkh script
([
7de694b7 # BIP32 root key fingerprint 
/0' # perform one hardened derivation at index 0 on the root key
/0' # perform one hardened derivation at index 0 on the previous derivation's output
/7' # perform one hardened derivation at index 7 on the previous derivation's output
]
032c27921f2d15e7eca768c0e8a8b1aeb863328c74d6c194d41dde2888d4b0e75b # this should be your resulting public key
))
#6z7uwusp # checksum information for the entire key descriptor
```

The full key descriptor reference is available [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/19a354b11f85a3c6c81ff83bf702bf7a40cf5046/doc/descriptors.md).

To go from the public key to the address, you can perform the steps as outlined [here](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/#creation-of-p2sh-p2wpkh-address).

Comment: Ok, I would like to understand how it works: I have a P2SH address and to obtain this UTXO I have provided my compres. public key. The sender of the trans. had a Red.Script and the generated Lock.Script is in the OP_HASH160 Red.Script OP_EQUAL format. So, what I find in the UTXO Redeem Script must be the HASH160 of the compressed key present in the Descriptor. I don't know well the hardened derivation mechanism ... the UTXO are related to 3 different addresses which correspond to 3 different derivations of the same public key (for this reason they have the same fingerprint?), correct?